# Intersecting variable number of points with multiple polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

This might be a pretty simple question, but I just can't think of a proper query to solve it.

I would like to intersect a number of points (can range from one to pretty much anything depending on the user's input) with a number of single polygons (the polygons are all in one table).

To be specific, I want to set the value of a field (let's call it "check") in the polygon table to 1 whenever it intersects with a point from the point table.

Here's a screenshot to clarify what I want to do[image]

The field "check" of that one cell that intersects with the points should be set to 1.

My query so far looks like this:

```
select * from raster2km     
where ( ST_Intersects( (select geom from points), (select the_geom from raster2km) ) = true)
```

But naturally it doesn't work since it returns more than one geometry.

Any suggestions? I'd be really grateful.

EDIT: I tried to run the query Jakub Kania suggested, however i just keep on getting error messages saying "invalid join selectivity". I tried to run it with a significantly smaller table containing "only" 5000 polygon" but the error message stays the same.

EDIT: I can now confirm that the query presented by Jakub Kania works on a table with only a few polygons (I tested it with 10 polygons).
The problem is that it is crucial for me to maintain that high amount of polygons.

Maybe I use the wrong approach, but I just can't think of another way to do it.

LAST EDIT: I came up with a workaround that works perfectly: I get the coordinates of the points, use the google api to get the name of the town they are located in and use that name to do a query with postgresql that is much, much faster than intersecting.

To conclude, Jakub Kania's query works just fine, but it's not suitable for very large datasets. Using reverse geocoding is a possible alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ST_Intersects()` is a function so you can just use it in `ON` clause of a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM raster2km AS r
JOIN points AS p
  ON  ST_Intersects(p.geom,r.geom)
```

Comment: I just get this error message:
ERROR: invalid join selectivity: 40327968.000000
SQL state: XX000

Comment: @gis_chris But that is the way to do it (http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet). Check that you didn't make a typo and that you have the latest version of postgis

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.3.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit" and no typo found.

Comment: I have seen this error when doing massive numbers of geometry unions and intersections. As far as I know it is a GEOS error. My suggestion would be to put all of this in a loop in plpgsql, to at least narrow down where the error might be coming from.

Comment: Define massive. The shape I uploaded to the database is around 2.7 mb. However, it does contain a sum of 21765 single polygons.